# R markdown: Knitr: histogram dows not show when document titles are present

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have been battling with a curious problem and would appreciate if someone can help me. I am using the latest version of R Studio and packages.

````
---
title: "XYZ"
author: "ACB"
date: "Tuesday, October 21, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---

typing `r data(mtcars)`. 

Some text

```{r}
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
levels(mtcars$am) <-c("Automatic", "Manual")
```

Some text

```{r fig.align='center', fig.height=4}
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am=="Automatic"], breaks=12, main="mpg for automatic vehicles", xlab="mpg", xlim=c(10, 35))
```
````

If I Knit the above to PDF the histogram does not show; if the output is to HTML it works.

Thanks

Comment: It would appear `fig.align` doesn't sit well with LaTeX.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You are right. It does not work yet when the output is not HTML. I plan to fix it in the next version of knitr. Related: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/148

Comment: I had the same problem with `knit`ing to Word. Sounds like Yihui is on it! Thanks!